# Parse soap xml document php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have this SOAP response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <pkup:PickupPendingStatusResponse xmlns:pkup="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Pickup/v1.1">
        <common:Response xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
            <common:ResponseStatus>
                <common:Code>1</common:Code>
                <common:Description>Success</common:Description>
            </common:ResponseStatus>
        </common:Response>
        <pkup:PendingStatus>
            <pkup:PickupType>01</pkup:PickupType>
            <pkup:ServiceDate>20141006</pkup:ServiceDate>
            <pkup:PRN>2929AONCALL</pkup:PRN>
            <pkup:OnCallStatusCode>001</pkup:OnCallStatusCode>
            <pkup:PickupStatusMessage>Received at dispatch</pkup:PickupStatusMessage>
            <pkup:BillingCode>01</pkup:BillingCode>
            <pkup:ContactName>Shipping Mgr.</pkup:ContactName>
            <pkup:ReferenceNumber>OnCallNextDayAir</pkup:ReferenceNumber>
        </pkup:PendingStatus>
    </pkup:PickupPendingStatusResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I need to get the `PickupPendingStatusResponse->Response->ResponseStatus->Description`.

I also would like to get `pkup:PendingStatus` into an `array` and be able to get each of it's children values.

Comment: How are you currently fetching the response? Consider SoapClient extension to avoid XML parsing. Otherwise, look at SimpleXML extension

Comment: I am using a client to get the response. $c = new SoapClient($wsdl). $response = $client->getRates($params)

Comment: Then i would think your value is at `$response->ResponseStatus->Description`

Comment: I am getting the xml document as a string returned from $client->getRates($params). Usually I am returned an object but not this time for some reason

Comment: SoapClient kind of sucks for document literal style. Then again, document literal is pretty awful anyway, and SOAP in general is a mess. Most people use nusoap for fussy wsdl's, you may want to explore that as real solution

Comment: Actually, Zend Soap is apparently the new alternative of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I used the DOMDocument class to get the nodes

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($upsResponse);
$PRN =  $doc->getElementsByTagName('PRN')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$success =  $doc->getElementsByTagName('Description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```